# Not doing ramadan for 1 day Please Read

Tags: ramadan

Salaam everyone ramadan kareem

So i am a 13 year old boy i and fasted everyday from day now but the thing is i haven't done suhoor anytime. I am not that hungry but very thirsty. I tried eating much at iftar but still.
So first question am i permitted to not fast for a day and make it up later? because i havent done suhoor for like 1,5 weeks.

Regards

Comment: Why do you want to skip a fast?

Comment: Are you mature (baligh/mukallaf)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to die or face permanent bodily harm if you fast? If not then you are not permitted to skip it since you have not any other valid excuse (e.g. illness, travel, pregnancy).